# using sed to capture groups of indeterminate length and a multitude of characters

Tags: sed, replace

I am struggling to grasp the sed command.

I am working with gene annotation files. In particular, I convert gff3 to gtf files needed to execute cellranger-arc mkref. Both gffread and agat fail to do so perfectly on gff3 files from ncbi. My agat-gtf file doesn't contain 'transcript_id' as is.

The gtf format is a tab delimited format, with the final column being for attributes. The attributes are separated using semicolons. Currently, my agat-gtf file has 'locus_tag' descriptors which I want to replace as 'transcript_id' with necessary quote marks around the name of the transcript. As an example, I want

```
  ... ; locus_tag AbcdE_f1 ; ...
```

to be replaced with

```
 ... ; transcript_id "AbcdE_f1" ; ...
```

I have tried
`sed -i.bak "s/locus_tag\([0-9a-zA-Z ,._-]{1,}\);/transcript_id \"1\";/g" myFile.gtf`, but it does nothing. 
 Thanks for any help.

As per request (I'll include two lines as input) typical input

sample:

```
ChrPT   RefSeq  exon    956 981 .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:38831453"  ; ID "nbis-exon-1"  ; Parent PhpapaC_p1 ; gbkey exon ; gene "3' rps12"  ; locus_tag PhpapaC_p1 ; product "ribosomal protein S12" <br>
ChrPT   RefSeq  gene    1033    1500    .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:2546745"  ; ID "nbis-gene-17"  ; Name rps7 ; gbkey Gene ; gene rps7 ; gene_biotype protein_coding ; locus_tag PhpapaCp002
```

Desired output:

```
ChrPT   RefSeq  exon    956 981 .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:38831453"  ; ID "nbis-exon-1"  ; Parent PhpapaC_p1 ; gbkey exon ; gene "3' rps12"  ; transcript_id "PhpapaC_p1" ; product "ribosomal protein S12" <br>
ChrPT   RefSeq  gene    1033    1500    .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:2546745"  ; ID "nbis-gene-17"  ; Name rps7 ; gbkey Gene ; gene rps7 ; gene_biotype protein_coding ; transcript_id "PhpapaCp002"
```

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\<locus_tag\>[ \t]([^ \t]*)/transcript_id "\1"/' input_file
ChrPT   RefSeq  exon    956 981 .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:38831453"  ; ID "nbis-exon-1"  ; Parent PhpapaC_p1 ; gbkey exon ; gene "3' rps12"  ; transcript_id "PhpapaC_p1" ; product "ribosomal protein S12" <br>
ChrPT   RefSeq  gene    1033    1500    .   +   .   Dbxref "GeneID:2546745"  ; ID "nbis-gene-17"  ; Name rps7 ; gbkey Gene ; gene rps7 ; gene_biotype protein_coding ; transcript_id "PhpapaCp002"
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed to change the code slightly to sed -E 's/\<locus_tag\>[ \t]([^ \t]*)/transcript_id \"\1\"/'  , but it works. And thanks for the help with formatting. I'll try to do better next time

Answer (score 1):

FYI using AGAT properly should definitely provide a proper GTF file with transcript_id

Comment: The input GFF3 file I used as input for running AGAT was from ncbi: (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_005087.2). The agat command I used: `agat_convert_sp_gxf2gxf.pl -gff file.gff3 --out file.gtf -gvo 2.5`. I still had many issues (the attributes column didn't specifically have "gene_id" or "transcript_id". The   first attribute (`Dbxref "GeneID:xxxxx"`) could be changed to `gene_id "xxxxx"`, but some instances of the first attribute had two quoted strings (e.g. `Dbxref "Genbank:NP_904165.1"  "GeneID:2546745"  ; `. Many other issues to make it for `cellranger-arc mkref` compatible.

Comment: With AGAT <v1.0.0  agat_convert_sp_gxf2gxf.pl with using --gvo 2.5 is not appropriate because it uses the bioperl parser that just formats the 9th column as gtf but does not pay attention to attribute types and values.  agat_convert_sp_gff2gtf.pl is the appropriate script that will generate correct GTF output. Since AGAT v1.0.0 you can also use agat_convert_sp_gxf2gxf.pl but you will have to modify the config file to specify that you want GTF output.